# Error using uic to convert .ui file to .py file in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am trying to write a program in python that will convert a .ui file in the same folder (created in Qt Designer) into a .py file. This is the code for this extremely basic program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import uic

with open('exampleinterface.py', 'w') as fout:
    uic.compileUi('exampleinterface.ui', fout)
```

It gives the following error (with long path names shortened):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
>       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>   File ".../Documents/Python/UiToPy/minimalconvert.py", line 11, in 
>       uic.compileUi('exampleinterface.ui', fout)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic__init__.py", line 173, in compileUi
>       winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, pyfile, from_imports, resource_suffix)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 140, in compileUi
>       w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 974, in parse
>       document = parse(filename)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
>       tree.parse(source, parser)
>
> File "...\Python32_3.5\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 594, in parse
>       self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
>   xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working, and if there is a solution?

**Note:** I know that there are other ways to convert a .ui file into a .py file, but I am looking for one that I can easily integrate into a python program, without calling an outside file.

Comment: Works fine for me. Obviously there is something wrong with your `ui` file - but since you didn't provide it, there's not much more that can be said.

Comment: You should check if the same file can be converted in the regular way using `pyuic4` in the command line. If it doesn't work there either, your .ui file is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ekhumoro and mwormser. The problem was indeed the .ui file.
I retried it with a new .ui file and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

This error popped because my `.ui` file was not saved with the recent changes that i had done. The file name showed the `asterisk(*)` mark in the file name. Once i saved the file with changes it could be converted into a `.py` file.